# Python passing arguments using command prompt

Tags: python, youtube

I am new to Python. However, I am trying to run the code ([Found here](https://github.com/google/vogon/blob/master/vogon.py)) using the command prompt and I am getting the following error:

```
usage: vogon.py [-h] [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                [--noauth_local_webserver]
                [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
                [--youtube_upload] [--preview_line PREVIEW_LINE]
                config_file
vogon.py: error: argument --youtube_upload: ignored explicit argument 'Yes'
```

The command I used to execute it is :

```
>python vogon.py --config_file=sample_win.json --auth_host_name=http://localhost/ --auth_host_port=8080 --logging_level=DEBUG --youtube_upload=Yes --preview_line=2
```

How can I solve this ?

**UPDATE**

```
> File "vogon.py", line 351, in <module>
>     main()   File "vogon.py", line 348, in main
>     generate_videos(args.config_file, args.youtube_upload, args.preview_line, args)   File "vogon.py", line 68, in
> generate_videos
>     video = generate_video(config, row, (i + 1))   File "vogon.py", line 100, in generate_video
>     filters = filter_strings(image_overlays, text_overlays)   File "vogon.py", line 127, in filter_strings
>     ovr['y'], ovr['h_align'], ovr['start_time'], KeyError: 'h_align

'
```

Comment: That's just a flag, surely; just use `--youtube_upload` without a value.

Comment: if so it says too few arguiments

Comment: any help here ?

Comment: Also, `--config_file` is not an option. `config_file` is just the name of a required positional argument.

Comment: If `--youtube_upload` accepted an argument, it would be displayed as something like `[--youtube_upload YOUTUBE_UPLOAD]`, not `[--youtube_upload]` alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is defined with

```
parser.add_argument("--youtube_upload",
        help="Upload generated videos to YouTube",
        action="store_true")
```

`--youtube_upload` doesn't take any arguments; drop the `=YES`.

The full command (split across multiple lines using shell line continuation) would appear to be

```
python vogon.py --auth_host_name=http://localhost/ \
                --auth_host_port=8080 \
                --logging_level=DEBUG \
                --youtube_upload \ 
                --preview_line=2 \
                sample_win.json
```

Comment: what do you mean ? is it `python app.py --youtube_upload=YES` ??  but it gives the same error message

Comment: Still  unable to get this sorted. Will you be able to give me the full command so I can try it out in 'cmd' ? I have tried various options but with luck.

Comment: It's just `python app.py --youtube_upload`, no argument at all.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated post. I have included the error that I have get when I tried your solution

Comment: That looks like it has absolutely nothing to do with the current question. Dropping `=YES` makes the `argparse`-based parser happy; now you just have problem with whatever `vogon` is.